# Rails: how can I pass a collection as :object to render() without it iterating over it for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, partial

I have a partial which I'm rendering with `render(:partial => "list", :object => my_collection)` which looks like this:

```
<ul>
<% list.each do |l| %>
<li>l</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

However, when I run this I find that what's getting passed into the partial is actually one of the children of `my_collection` rather than the collection itself.  Presumably this is a piece of rails magic to to implement "render a partial for each item in a collection" but in this instance I want to pass the collection itself in.  How can I do that, without resorting to using a member variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:locals => {:list => my_collection}
```

instead of :object. :object is there to render the partial for each member of the object.